# Isolate digital switching from audio circuit

Tags: amplifier, dc-motor, inductor, h-bridge

I'm using an L298 H-Bridge to drive a DC motor. The motor is spinning a magnet across a guitar pickup at ~30 Hz. That signal is then amplified and sent to a speaker.

However, the output signal also contains a fairly constant (and loud) sound at ~10 kHz. I believe this is coming from the L298 H-Bridge's switching circuitry.

Obviously I don't have the H-bridge connected in the audio circuit. But that switching signal is making its way into the audio at some stage, either from the pickup coil, the op-amp amplifier or the wires themselves.

I don't think a band-reject filter is the answer here. What physical things can I do to get rid of this noise?

Comment: Look for positive stray feedback and suppress with shielding. Then post a schematic and photos

Comment: Who (what) is PWM'ing the L298 ? If you don't need much power, using a linear regulator to adjust the motor speed would be practical. If it is a low cost brushed DC motor, then the commutation (brushes) will of course generate lots of electrical noise.
A brushless DC motor would not generate as much noise itself, but likely the controller would be PWM'ed and it would generate noise.

Comment: You're going to have 10KHz ripple in the motor currents which will result in a magnetic field that will easily couple into your pickup.  Can you double the PWM frequency so you can't hear it?  (Or if you can hear 20 kHz bump it up a little higher.)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 What kind of shielding would work here? The induced current will also fall off with distance, but the whole system is quite packed together :)

Comment: @jp314 An arduino is controlling the PWM. Yeah, it's only a cheap 6v DC motor with an encoder doing PID calculations. I agree that there shouldnt be any noise coming from or into the motor.

Comment: @JohnD That's a great idea, haha. I do wonder if having all that amplified ultrasonic noise existing in the audio will waste power, not that it's a constraint here tho.

Comment: @ThomasCoor it would increase your switching losses, but probably not cause a lot more loss through the amp and speaker, depending on frequency response.  The higher frequency will lower the ripple current so there's less to amplify as well.